# could you please explain connection pooling in java and also is there any default size of connection pool?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i saw in java portal different people given different answers like max size of connection pool is 100 and min size of connection pool size is 0.could you please explain someone what is the default size,max size,min size of connection pooling.

Comment: Each pool has its default values, that you can set to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Connection pooling is very similar to object pooling. Meaning of these values might differ for a specific implementation, but generally these numbers define the main pooling strategy parameters. I.e. `min` could mean that the pool would contain not less than `min` number of idle or active connections. Max would define a higher boundary for active connections. Another important measurement is `keepAliveTime` or TTL which defines how soon idle connection would be closed.

All these numbers very much depend on the environment, i.e. a cost to open a new connection or total throughput drop for the newly opened connection.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring a connection pool depends on how heavy your web application is. If you're having tough time with configuring your own connection pool then try [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/), this is what we've been using in our java web application and configure your connection pool according to your requirement.